# How do I access the contents of a variable from a file imported in a console?

Tags: python

I have a file, light.py that I'm trying to debug. In the python console, I type "import light" and it runs the program. But I want to check the contents of some variables by typing the variables. How do I do that?

Comment: You need to accept some answers, you only accepted 64%

Comment: But what if I have lots of questions that haven't been satisfactorily answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a variable named `test` in your file `light.py`

```
import light
print light.test
```

If you want to test DURING the running of your program you need to use [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) to debug the execution